# Unable to accurately keep a running total of checkboxes checked in a Typescript ToDo app

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

My **goal is to track the total number of checkboxes that are checked** (and also subtracting from the total when they become unchecked). My motivation behind this is show some sort of announcement once x number of boxes become checked. (For now I'll just settle for a console.log message.)

At the moment, the total only increases if I click the checkbox for an individual task multiple times. If "add" 3 tasks and click each of those 3 checkboxes *one* time, I the same log of a total 0 three times ("checkCount"). I've included a screenshot of what I see. I've also included my primary App.tsx and ToDoTask.tsx files.

I want to understand the logic and I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I'm mapping/creating tasks?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

[image]

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { ITask } from "./Interfaces";
import TodoTask from "./Components/TodoTask";
import todoImg from "./todo.png";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

// React func comp type `React.FC`
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState<string>(""); //type string

  // state hook with type `ITask[]`-- array of objects with properties `taskName` and `id`
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState<ITask[]>([]);

  const [taskCount, setTaskCount] = useState<number>(1);

  // event handler for handling changes in input fields--typing is specified with `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`; return nothing so void
  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    if (event.target.name === "task") {
      setTask(event.target.value);
    }
  };

  const addTask = (): void => {
    //return nothing so void
    // creates new task object w/properties `taskName` and `deadline`
    const newTask = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      taskName: task,
    };
    //console.log(newTask.id);
    // adds new task object to the `todo` state and resets input fields
    setTodo([...todo, newTask]);
    setTask("");
    setTaskCount(taskCount + 1);
    console.log("taskCount", taskCount);
    /*  if (taskCount === 10) {
      alert("10 tasks: you can do this!");
    } */
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    //type React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      addTask();
    }
  };

  // event handler for completing a task; takes in a `taskNameToDelete` string type; returns nothing so voide
  const completeTask = (taskNameToDelete: string): void => {
    // filters out the task with the specified name and updates the `todo` state
    setTodo(
      todo.filter((task) => {
        setTaskCount(taskCount - 1);
        console.log("taskCount", taskCount - 2);
        return task.id !== taskNameToDelete;
      })
    );
  };
  //changed this from task.taskName to task.id so that tasks are deleted by unique id (uuid)
  //before, when deleting based on taskName, if multiples tasks had the same text, ALL of them would be deleted when one was deleted

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <div className="banner">
          <img src={todoImg} alt="to do banner" />
        </div>
        <div className="entry">
          <h1>To-Do List</h1>
          <div className="inputContainer">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="task"
              placeholder="Add a task:"
              value={task}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            />
            <button onClick={addTask}>Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="todoList">
        {todo.map((task: ITask) => {
          return (
            <TodoTask
              key={task.id}
              task={task}
              completeTask={() => completeTask(task.id)} //(see delete function above--was just completeTask=completeTask before)
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**TodoTask.tsx**

```
import { ITask } from "../Interfaces";
import { useState } from "react";

// Props interface defines the shape of the data that is passed as props to the TodoTask component
interface Props {
  // task is of type ITask from "../Interfaces"
  task: ITask;

  // takes a string parameter taskNameToDelete and returns nothing so type is void
  completeTask(taskNameToDelete: string): void;
}

const TodoTask = ({ task, completeTask }: Props) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [checkCount, setCheckCount] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleCheckboxClick = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    setCheckCount(checkCount + 1);
    console.log("checkCount", checkCount);
  };

  return (
    <div className="task">
      <div className="inputContainer">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={handleCheckboxClick}
          checked={isChecked}
        />
        <div className="content">
          <span style={{ backgroundColor: isChecked ? "#00800080" : "" }}>
            {task.taskName}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="buttonContainer">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            completeTask(task.taskName);
          }}
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default TodoTask;
```

While I've tried putting this into either file and in different locations within the code, I've primarily tried track the total with state:

```
const [checkCount, setCheckCount] = useState<number>(0);
```

Tracking it with a function:

```
  const handleCheckboxClick = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    setCheckCount(checkCount + 1);
    console.log("checkCount", checkCount);
  };
```

And attaching that to the input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckboxClick} checked={isChecked}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the check inside `completeTask`:

```
  const completeTask = (taskNameToDelete: string): void => {
    const newTodo = todo.filter((task) => task.id !== taskNameToDelete);
    setTodo(newTodo);
    if (newTodo.length > 10) {
      // do something
    };
  };
```

You don't need to keep the todo count in state, since you can derived it:

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState<ITask[]>([]);
const taskCount = todo.length;
```